# Frequency Conversion annual to monthly

Tags: ms-access

I have a access database of contracts, fields are simply [ContractID], [Start], [End], [Value$]

The start and end dates span 3-5 years and the Value is for the entire contract.

I want to graphically portray this data divided into monthly or quarterly columns in an access report without having to create new fields. I sense there is an easy way but can't figure it out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a date to Month or Year using formulas. For example `Year(Date)` for the Year or `DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month(Date()),1)` for Month.